# Jest tests fail -- using ts-jest -- when in a ES2020/ESNEXT TS project

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a VueJS project which uses ViteJS to transpile (this works fine) and clearly when ViteJS is involved the resultant output is native ES modules but for Jest testing I was still using **ts-jest** and my normal old Jest config:

`jest.config.ts`

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  // roots: ["tests", "src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^[/]{0,1}~/(.*)$": resolve(process.cwd(), "src", "$1"),
  },
  testMatch: ["**/?(*[-.])+(spec|test).ts"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-extended"],
};

export default config;
```

And now suddenly I'm getting this error:

[image: error message]

Now this error seems to center around the new `import.meta` meta-property. This is a new property but I was under the impression that using "ES2020" and "ESNEXT" as a target would allow me to use this. In fact, Vite/Rollup have no problem transpiling this nor does vs-code give me any warnings but between Jest, ts-jest, and Typescript something hasn't given the wrong "target" to the Jest test runner (my tsconfig.json file is correct).

Now I swear, it *was* working even with this reference to `import.meta` but somehow now it is not. I'm not sure what in my ENV has changed. Possibly a slightly new node version (I'm using `14.17.6` currently)? Probably a slightly newer version of Typescript (`4.4.2` is what I'm using currently).

Anyway, does anyone know how I can get past this?

---

Note:

- my tsconfig.json reads like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",

    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    },

  },
  "include": ["src", "test"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Still appears to be an issue with the Jest library.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12952

> we enforce CJS, might be we should tweak this. It's unfortunate this requires using a loader, tho... Would love to figure out a good way for Jest to just ask ts-node to load the config for us without caring about what flavour of module system it's written in

https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/3648#issuecomment-1160480989

> Note that, ts-jest doesn't process jest.config.ts. jest.config.ts is proccessed by ts-node.
>
> When you put console.log(import.meta) in jest.config.ts, ts-node will transform the config file into either CJS or ESM syntax and then jest will process the jest.config.ts file.
> Your issue is not in the scope of ts-jest.